# BFS running time O(E) for a connected graph

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

Let G be a connected graph.
I know the running time of BFS for any graph is O(m+n), where n is the number of vertices and m the number of edges.
For a connected graph we have m>=n-1 so n<=m+1. So the running time of BFS is O(m+n) \subseteq O(m+m+1)=O(m). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A connected graph, by definition, has a path between every node. The longest such path would require traversing all nodes, O(m) from start to finish, n (or m+1.)

I'd probably state this a bit differently, but I think you're correct.